# Android webview - how to skip url?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview with custom webview client. I'm intercepting requests with:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    // ...
}
```

sometimes I'm getting informations about custom events from webview in a form of a link:

> xyz://do-something

When it happens I want webview to ignore it. But 'shouldInterceptRequest' has to return something and when I'm returning 'null' instead of my page it shows: 'unknown url xyz://do-something'. How can I deal with that? How can I intercept the link but disable action on webview side?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a string comparison from the site that you are in and the site that you want to go to.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I can't use 'public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)', it has to be 'public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)'.